Can I paint a wall cabinet and the moulding at the same time?
I'm painting a wall cabinet and the moulding on it the same color.
Can I paint them at the same time, or do I need to
mask them off and paint each separately?
I have tried researching my question on multiple websites, but I haven't found any specific answers.

masking is only needed for different colors

The purpose of masking is to prevent different colors on unwanted surfaces.
In your case masking is not needed if you use same color.
However masking is needed between the mould and the wall.

.... Unless you have a steady and careful hand, and at least one brush with a fine enough edge to paint up to that line but not past it. Masking is arguably more needed for a pro for whom time is money than for an amateur who is willing to spend more time. Of course if you are an amateur who doesn't want to spend that time, masking is cheap and easy...

Only caveat I would add is if you're doing same color, but different sheen.  But even then, maybe freehanding is good enough—only someone looking closely will be able to see the difference at the "joint" between sheens.

@keshlam "Masking is arguably more needed for a pro" don't you have that backwards?

Maybe? A pro's goal is to finish the job quickly and cleanly and move on to the the next, and not having to be over careful about edges is worth the minute or two of setup time and a few cents if tape. An amateur may be more willing to try to deal with the fiddly edge, perhaps aided by a momentary mask like a piece of cardboard. ... Flip a coin, take your choice, I guess. Odds are higher than the amateur will try to skip masking... I think?

@keshlam Based on anecdotal experience (limited) and various YouTube videos, etc. my impression is: Amateurs definitely should tape, but could skip it at the cost of lots of time, super pros (many years of experience) may not bother to tape routine stuff if they are using a brush or roller (can't avoid masking when spraying) because they are so good and fast that the extra time to mask isn't worth it. But that most pros - been doing it professionally for a few years but not "a lifetime" - mask to avoid having to repaint errors.
